# Creating a copy of a instance variable in python

Tags: python

In the expand() method in the following piece of code, the class variable *state* is not being assigned anything directly. However when I call the method, the state class variable gets altered. Why does this happen and how can I avoid it? I want to create copies of the state list, put 1's or 2's where there is a '*' and return the copies without altering the state variable *state.*

For example if

self.state = `[['*','*','*'],['*','*','*'],['*','*','*']]`

the child states should be -

```
[[1,'*','*'],['*','*','*'],['*','*','*']]
[['*',1,'*'],['*','*','*'],['*','*','*']]
[['*','*',1],['*','*','*'],['*','*','*']]
[['*','*','*'],[1,'*','*'],['*','*','*']]
[['*','*','*'],['*',1,'*'],['*','*','*']]
[['*','*','*'],['*','*',1],['*','*','*']]
[['*','*','*'],['*','*','*'],[1,'*','*']]
[['*','*','*'],['*','*','*'],['*',1,'*']]
[['*','*','*'],['*','*','*'],['*','*',1]]
```

but I am getting the following output -

```
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
```

---

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, state, node_type, parent=None):
        self.state=state
        self.node_type=node_type
        self.parent=parent 
        self.depth=0

        if parent:
            self.depth = parent.depth + 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Node %s>" % (self.state,)

    def expand(self):
        child_nodes = []

        for i in range(0, len(self.state)):
            for j in range(0, len(self.state[0])):
                if self.state[i][j] == '*':
                    if self.node_type == 'max':
                        child_state = list(self.state)
                        child_state[i][j] = '1'
                        child_node = Node(child_state,'min',self)
                    elif self.node_type == 'min':
                        child_state = list(self.state)
                        child_state[i][j] = '2'
                        child_node = Node(child_state,'max',self)
                        child_nodes.append(child_node)

                    child_nodes.append(child_node)

        #print self.state
        return child_nodes
```

Comment: How did you *create* the `state` list that you passed to the instance?

Comment: @MartijnPieters `start_node = Node([['*','*','*'],['*','*','*'],['*','*','*']],'max') output =start_node.expand() `

Comment: @PeterWood: nope, I see the error now, it is not a dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`child_state = list(self.state)` creates a *shallow* copy of the list. This means any lists *contained* are not themselves copied, the new `child_state` list only contains references.

You can either use the [`copy.deepcopy()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to have Python recursively clone the nested structure, or use a list comprehension to copy the directly contained lists:

```
child_state = [list(sub) for sub in self.state]
```